# How does an issuer manage trustlines when authorization is required?

Tags: accounts, assets, compliance, trustline

If someone issues an asset from an account where AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED is set to True, how does a new account wishing to hold that asset initialize getting the trustline setup?

Is it up to the owner of the new account to contact that issuer and prove they own the address in question and then the issuer creates the trustline on their end?

Answer (score 1):

The issuer/anchor will have to figure out a process for that, and it can vary significantly depending on their compliance process.

For example, an anchor may require a customer to register on their website providing KYC information (along with their stellar address), and if everything checks out, they'd execute the [Allow Trust](https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/list-of-operations.html#allow-trust) operation on the address.

With [Lumen](http://github.com/0xfe/lumen) you can do this:

```
$ lumen flags BankOfCanada auth_required

# Bob creates a new trustline to CAD.
$ lumen trust create bob CAD:BankOfCanada 1000

# Bank-of-canada authorizes it.
$ lumen trust allow bob CAD:BankOfCanada --signers BankOfCanada
```

You can read more about this [here](https://github.com/0xfe/hacking-stellar/blob/master/3-assets.md#setting-asset-limits).

Comment: Ok, so technically anyone in the network can request a trustline to any asset on the network and the request is stored on the ledger? If so, does BankOfCanada see all pending requests attached to their account or do they need to scan for accounts that have a trustline created but still not authorized?

Answer (score 0):

well, although it's been a while but since I'm just crossing the same situation worth noting that an Authority of an [Asset] (Issuer/Distributor) or any other [Account] the holds an amount of the so-called [Custom Asset] with "AUTHORIZATION_REQUIRED is set to True" needs to retrieve a list of [Pending Trustlines] and verify them based on it's own specifications, then Authorize/Disauthorize their [Trustline] by sending an [AllowTrust] Operation to the Network.
(Retrieving the list of [Pending Trustlines] is my current challenge though).